# Moq Setup Method to return correct result

Tags: c#, moq, nunit-3.0

Need help is it possible to manage Moq setup like this

```
repositoryMock.Setup(s => s.Find(It.IsAny<object>())).Returns(() => DataList().FirstOrDefault(w => w.Id == It.IsAny<Guid>()));
```

Why I'm asking, because with this setup I always get return null, but if I put only to return DataList().FirstOrDefault(), it is returning correctly the first element in the list. My question is how I can manage DataList with "n" elements where element which I need will be in the middle and when mock setup is run to return if element exists?

**Updates**

```
private IList<Data> DataList()
{
        List<Data> dataList = new List<Data> {

            new Data
            {
                Id =  new Guid("299cd2b5-ab47-4006-9a47-c35e4770e9b1"),

            },
            new Data
            {
                Id = new Guid("279cd2b5-ab47-4006-9a47-c35e4770e9b1"),

            }
        };
        return dataList;
    }
```

Kind Regards,

Comment: What does the function `DataList()` return?

Comment: Please check Updates

Comment: if you want to return at least on object your DataList() must return at least on object. and must take care of this  `w => w.Id == It.IsAny<Guid>()`

Comment: Why not just change `FirstOrDefault(...)` to `FirstOrDefault()`? Since the criteria is obviously meant to just give the first element anyway.

Comment: I need to test all possible conditions. Sometimes Id will exist sometimes not.

Comment: but your code does not test that. `DataList()` is static and will always return the same data. It does not make sense to me to have a criteria on the selection from that list - especially when the criteria does not use the input to the `Find` function...

Comment: It is fake that in order to test method. I will be glad to listen for better way of doing that.

Comment: @DanijelBoksan Capture the passed argument in the Returns delegate and use that to filter the list (check provided [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60105058/5233410) below)

Answer (score 1):

Capture the passed argument in the `Returns` delegate and use that to filter the list

```
repositoryMock
    .Setup(_ => _.Find(It.IsAny<object>()))
    .Returns((object arg) => {
        if(arg is Guid id)
            return DataList().FirstOrDefault(w => w.Id == id);
        return null;
    });
```

This assumes that the definition of the mocked member is `IRepostory<T>.Find(object id)` given the use of `It.IsAny<object>()` in the expectation expression.

If however the definition was `IRepostory<T>.Find(Guid id)` then the setup would be slightly different

```
repositoryMock
    .Setup(_ => _.Find(It.IsAny<Guid>()))
    .Returns((Guid id) => DataList().FirstOrDefault(w => w.Id == id));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return at least on object.

```
repositoryMock.Setup(s => s.Find(It.IsAny<IBaseRepository>())).Returns(() => DataList().FirstOrDefault(w => w.Id == It.Is<Guid>()));
```

Comment: You want different results based on different ids?

Comment: I want to be return Data which has specific Id.

Comment: so use `It.Is<Guid>` against `It.IsAny<Guid>`

Comment: IRepository<Data>.Find(["159cd2b5-ab47-4006-9a47-c85e4770e9b1"]) invocation failed with mock behavior Strict.
All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.

Comment: Replace Find with FindAll

Comment: I need to use Find not FindAll

Comment: Does repositoryMock has a base Interface or base Class? if through replace the object with that.

Comment: It has, I will go through. But what can be a problem?

Comment: I guess it could lead Moq to always return null.